# TextMate: how to highlight the entire line to copy and paste?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I find the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> hard to press, and for some reason <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> doesn't seem to highlight the entire line.

I want to *copy* the line into my *clipboard*. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Command-LeftArrow` `Shift-DownArrow` is one way

Comment: is there a way to delete everything after the cursor on a line? i hate pressing fn-delete so many times.

Answer (score 7):

To highlight a line in TextMate, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Triple-click, then hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd-leftArrow               # to get cursor to beginning of line

shift-cmd-rightArrow        # to highlight entire line

cmd-c                       # copy the line to clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate a line you can use this shortcut:

1. `Cmd + left arrow` to go at the beginning of the line
2. `Ctrl + Shift + D` to duplicate the entire line below the one you want to duplicate

---

> Duplicate Line / Selection (⌃⇧D) — this will duplicate the current line, leaving the caret in the same column on the new line, or if there is a selection, duplicate that.

Source: [textMate official website](https://macromates.com/manual/en/bundles#text)

---

**PERSONAL WARNING:**

Selecting a word, or whatever, and apply this shortcut will duplicate next to the original one. Not below.

**TIPS**

If you want to move your new duplicated line or whatever:

1. `Ctrl + Cmd + arrow up` will move up
2. `Ctrl + Cmd + arrow down` will move down

Happy coding